# How to upload images from react naitve to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am new to React-Native and I'm currently working on a project where the user can upload multiple images to database. I am using react-native-image-picker library to select images from the device memory. However, I don't know how to use the returned images path to upload them to MySQL database using php. What library should I use to upload the images to the database? 
TIA!

Comment: Do you want to store the image in some folder/s3 and store the only name in your MySQL table?

Comment: Just flow this: https://reactnativecode.com/upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file using`new FormData()` and use that file to upload.

```
const name = `${guid()}.jpg` // just to assign a new uuid
const { uri } = response // resonse from ImageViewer
const data = new FormData() // eslint-disable-line
data.append('name', 'avatar') // you can append anyone.
data.append('avatar', {
  uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
  name,
})
```